# Pandas: renaming columns that have the same name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe that has duplicated column names a, b and b. I would like to rename the second b into c.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6], "b1": [7, 8, 9]})
df.rename(index=str, columns={'b1' : 'b'})
```

Trying this with no success..

```
df.rename(index=str, columns={2 : "c"})
```

Comment: accept the answer which suits you best in order to clear from the Queue.

Answer (score 9):

try:

```
>>> df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always just manually rename all the columns.

```
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

These solutions don't take into account the problem with having many cols.
Here is a solution where, independent on the amount of columns, you can rename the columns with the same name to a unique name

```
 df.columns = ['name'+str(col[0]) if col[1] == 'name' else col[1] for col in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are ordered and you want lettered columns, don't type names out manually. This is prone to error.

You can use [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase), assuming you have a maximum of 26 columns:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'b1'])

df.columns = list(ascii_lowercase[:len(df.columns)])

print(df.columns)

Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do:

```
df.columns = ['a','b','c']
```